# Universal wxPython Styles

Tags: python, wxpython

I'm fairly new to wxPython, and have been using it to build a GUI. However, I find it tedious to use "wx.Font" and then "SetFont" to make changes. Is there anyway to universally change the style for all fonts in my gui?

Answer (score 1):

You have to set the font for the parent of the widgets BEFORE you create the children widgets. See also:

- [How to change font for entire wxPython application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23339466/how-to-change-font-for-entire-wxpython-application)

Once you have the parent's font set, its children will inherit the font too. If you want to change the font after the program is running, you will have to iterate over all of the children and call each of their SetFont methods. You can get a list of children widgets using parent.GetChildren().

Comment: In my apps this works for many things, but there are a few elements and widgets that don't inherit this value automatically.

Comment: I wondered if that could happen. Are you using native widgets or custom widgets though?

Comment: Mostly native, to the best of my knowledge.  The places I see oddities are specific-use widgets anyway.  For a ComboTreeBox for example, the selected value displays correctly, but when I expand the control to view the available options the font isn't inherited in that panel.  I'd imagine it's something to do with how ComboTreeBox is implemented, but there are definitely widgets this won't apply fully to.

Comment: Yeah, custom widgets probably won't work and will need to have their font set explicitly.